# Not getting Get method retun values in postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, spring-restcontroller

Find My code below

PensionerDetails.java

```
package com.pension.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Embedded;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity 
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name="pensioner_detail")
public class PensionerDetail {

    @Id
    private String aadhar;
    private String name;
    private String DOB;
    private String Pan;
    private Double salary;
    private Double allowance;
    private String pension_class;
    @Embedded
    @Column(name="bank")
    private Bank bank;
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PensionerDetail [aadhar=" + aadhar + ", name=" + name + ", DOB=" + DOB + ", Pan=" + Pan + ", salary="
                + salary + ", allowance=" + allowance + ", pension_class=" + pension_class + ", bank=" + bank + "]";
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Bank.java

```
package com.pension.model;



import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Embeddable
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Bank {
    
    private String bank_name;
    private long acc_num;
    private String bank_type;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bank [bank_name=" + bank_name + ", acc_num=" + acc_num + ", bank_type=" + bank_type + "]";
    }

}
```

Pensionrepo.java

```
package com.pension.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.pension.model.PensionerDetail;

@Repository
public interface Pensionrepo extends JpaRepository<PensionerDetail, String>{
//
//  @Query("select p1_0.aadhar,p1_0.DOB,p1_0.Pan,p1_0.allowance,p1_0.acc_num,p1_0.bank_name,p1_0.bank_type,p1_0.name,p1_0.pension_class,p1_0.salary from PensionerDetail p1_0 where p1_0.aadhar=?1")
    public List<PensionerDetail> findByAadhar(String adhar);

}
```

PensionService.java

```
package com.pension.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.pension.model.PensionerDetail;
import com.pension.repository.Pensionrepo;

@Service
public class PensionService {
    
    @Autowired
    private Pensionrepo pensionrepo;

public String savePensionDetails(PensionerDetail pensionerDetail) {
        pensionrepo.save(pensionerDetail);
        return "PensionDetails are saved successfully";
    }

    public Optional<PensionerDetail> getPensionByAadhar(String Aadhar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(pensionrepo.findById(Aadhar));
        return pensionrepo.findById(Aadhar);
    }

    public List<PensionerDetail> pensionerDetails() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pensionrepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

PensionController.java

```
package com.pension.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.pension.model.PensionerDetail;
import com.pension.service.PensionService;

@RestController
public class PensionController {

    
    @Autowired
    private PensionService pensionService;
    

@PostMapping("/savePensionDetails")
    public String savePension( @RequestBody PensionerDetail pensionerDetail) {
        return pensionService.savePensionDetails(pensionerDetail);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/getByAadhar/{aadhar}")
    public Optional<PensionerDetail> getPensionByAadhar(@PathVariable String aadhar) {
        return pensionService.getPensionByAadhar(aadhar);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<PensionerDetail> pensionerDetails(){
        System.out.println(pensionService.pensionerDetails());
        return pensionService.pensionerDetails();
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/pension
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

[Find my mysql table detals here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBM1B.png)

I have created table and inserted values but when i am calling GetMapping methods i am able to see data in console but in post man it's just showing empty list. Can someone help me with this i just started learning spring.

I am expecting solution to my problem because in console i can see the data then why it's not printing the data in postman.

[Postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN3PB.png)

And For PostMapping Request i am getting this error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7uWt.png)

This is how i am passing values in postman [postman postmapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dMaU.png)

[while executing mvn clean compile i am getting build failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yajby.png)

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion in comments. To have an result in postman response body you should to do some changes.

Post method in controller layer should have a `@RequestBody` annotation:

```
@PostMapping("/savePensionDetails")
public String savePension(@RequestBody PensionerDetail pensionerDetail) {
    return pensionService.savePensionDetails(pensionerDetail);
}
```

In postman with the object from comments that you wrote, i got next one result:

```
{
  "name": "sravani",
  "DOB": "21/02/2001",
  "Pan": "Pan",
  "salary": 123.24,
  "allowance": 22.12,
  "pension_class": "pension",
  "bank": {
    "bank_name": "sbi",
    "acc_num": 1234,
    "bank_type": "govt"
  }
}
```

[image]

After all when i invoke the `/all` endpoint i`m going to have next one result:

[image]

Comment: in github link i missed the @Requestbody but in my code i have specified that annotation but i don't know why it's still not working

Comment: in postman are you doing `POST` request with json raw ?

Comment: Yes i am sending post request with json raw only